# another option for selenium & JBehave?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, jbehave

I have been working on ATCs during 2 months and I continue having problems with Chrome, Selenium and JBehave. The Chrome driver for selenium has some bugs. For example: Sometimes it said that the components could not be found or clickable. For this situation, I used a workaround, but it is a little hugly.

When I run the ATCs, sometimes one of then fail due to chrome selenium driver bugs!. Also, I don't like the JBehave's Reports.

Could somebody advise me another option to create ATCs?

Thanks!!!

Sarang

Answer (score 3):

Consider [Selenide](http://selenide.org) - it's specifically create to resolve all these timing/ajax/"element not found" poblems. Selenide is extremely simple to start with (much simpler than Thucydides) and can be used with any framework: Junit, TestNG, JBehave - you name it.

Answer (score 2):

I like Thucydides to write ATCs:
http://thucydides-webtests.com/2011/09/23/hello-world/

It has a nice report, with screenshots ...
You can write tests with easyb, junit or jbehave.
But it use selenium engine too.

Comment: Thanks Piantino! I think that the unique most used tool is Selenium for test website. I could not find other. :(

Comment: @Piantino. Is there any way to get Thucydides works with a normal JBehave project? without the new DSL from Thucydides. Regards!

Comment: You can write the stories in the same way, but you should add the requirements in the folders structure ([sample](http://java.dzone.com/articles/automated-acceptance-testing)). But Thucydides changes a little the test implementation, because you need use Step Classes to encapsulate user behavior. Without requirement and steps information Thucydides does not have traceability and reuse.